# Вытирание элемента в списке

Tags: c, алгоритм, список

Подскажите, почему, добавив отдельный случай для удаления элемента из списка, если он один, то удаляется только имя. Как правильно подкорректировать?

```
APTEKA* DeleteElem(APTEKA* pdel)
{
    if(pdel == head && pdel == tail)
    {
        head->next=NULL;
        head->prev=NULL;
        tail->next=NULL;
        tail->prev=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return NULL;
    }
    if(pdel == head)
    {
        head=head->next;
        head->prev=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return head;
    }
    if(pdel == tail)
    {
        tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return NULL;
    } else
    {
        APTEKA *pnext;

        pdel->next->prev=pdel->next;
        pnext=pdel->prev->next=pdel->next;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return pnext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает "удаляется только имя"? Какое еще "имя"? Отдельно: в чем смысл всех этих `... = NULL` в первой ветке?

Comment: Получается, если элемент, там имя, дата, цена и тд. Когда не было этой ветки, то при одном элементе программа падала. Первый иф я добавил, чтобы если есть только один элемент, который будет головой и хвостом одновременно, то он бы обнулил адреса.

Comment: Посмотрите на код, который я когда-то делал для демонстрации работы циклического двусвязного списка: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл только одну описку, :

```
APTEKA *pnext;

pdel->next->prev=pdel->next; // BUG
pnext=pdel->prev->next=pdel->next;
FreeElemMemo(pdel);
return pnext;
```

должно быть так:

```
APTEKA *pnext;

pdel->next->prev=pdel->prev;
pnext=pdel->prev->next=pdel->next;
FreeElemMemo(pdel);
return pnext;
```

Непонятен вопрос, что такое удаляет только имя?

Comment: Если **head==pdel==tail** то не стоит два раза обнулять указатели, даже одного раза не надо.